# Cannot create payouts: this account has requirements that need to be collected. in Laravel connecting to Stripe

Tags: laravel, api, stripe-payments

when want to connect to Stripe api to payout blance of my wallet to one customer account card, i faced this prblem.

acctually my laravel codes is:

```
   **$card_obj = $stripe->tokens->create([
        'card' => [
            'number' => '4000051240000005',
            'exp_month' => 8,
            'exp_year' => 2023,
            'cvc' => '314',
            'currency' => 'cad',
        ],
    ]);
    $account = $stripe->accounts->create([
        'type' => 'express',
        'country' => 'CA',
        'capabilities' => [
            'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
            'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
        ],
        'external_account' => $card_obj->id,
    ]);
    $payout = $stripe->payouts->create([
        'amount' => 1,
        'currency' => 'cad',
    ], [
        'stripe_account' => $account->id,
    ]);**
```

and the error that response returned:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckJhH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a Stripe connect account and immediately start creating payouts for it. If you were to retrieve that Account through the API you'd probably see that it has a number of `requirements` (see [api ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements)) that are still unfulfilled and `payouts_enabled` (see [api ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-payouts_enabled)) is false.

Connect account owners are expected to provide this missing information during the onboarding process (see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts for how to implement an onboarding flow), and once `payouts_enabled` becomes true on the Account you should be able to generate payouts.